# Mocking public method call inside ClassUnderTest | Deal with ArrayLists

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

Let's assume I have following scenario:

```
public class ClassUnderTest()
        {

        private Service myService;

        public SomeData method1(final InputData input) {
            final SomeData result = method2(myservice.getOutput(input));
            return result;
        }

        public SomeData method2(final OutputData output){
            //Do something with the OutputData
        }
   }
```

Now I want to test method1(). Since it's calling method2() I also need to assure everything inside method2() works fine. But the thing is, since I test all the methods, I would test method2() seperately.

So how do I know only test method1() without considering method2(). I would love to just use doNothing() when method2() get's called, but since it's the class I want to test and not mocked, so I can't do that. Or is there a possibility?

2.) How do I assert the equality of two ArrayList, when they both should just have two Objects with equal values. For example:

```
@Test 
public void test(){
User user1 = new User();
User user2 = new User();

user1.setMail("mail");
user2.setMail("mail");

list<User> list1 = new ArrayList<User>();
list<User> list2 = new ArrayList<User>();

list1.add(user1);
list2.add(user2);

assertEquals(list1,list2);

}
```

This would fail, since they are not equal Objects.

Comment: You're asking 2 unrelated questions in one. It would be better to split that in two separate questions.

Comment: If you're testing method2 thoroughly (and testing `myservice.getOutput(input)` thoroughly), and method1 is just a convenience method to call method2, then I'd probably just have a single method to prove that it really does work in some common situation. Add more tests for any validation that `method1` might do (e.g. that `input` is non-null)

Comment: Do you use any kind of mocking framework? It could help here, however the sample code makes me tell that there's a design smell somewhere; why make a same class return two completely unrelated items?

Comment: @fge Yes I use Mockito and yes the class I want to test is not implented really nicely. Nevertheless I need to test it, without doing refactoring. So that's the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should really ask the questions separately but I try to answer both:

**1. Partial Mocks with Mockito**

I am not really sure it is really advisable to mock partially. But with mockito it is possible. You could mock your `ClassUnderTest` and tell mockito to execute the real method when `method1` is called

```
ClassUnderTest mock = Mockito.mock(ClassUnderTest.class);
when(mock.method1()).thenCallRealMethod();
```

See http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/Mockito.html#partial_mocks

**2. Assertions on collections**

AssertJ gives you very nice assertions on collections - e.g.:

```
List<String> list1 = Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3");
List<String> list2 = Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3");
then(list1).containsExactlyElementsOf(list2);
```

see here for details
https://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/assertj-core-features-highlight.html#extracted-method-result-assertion

https://github.com/joel-costigliola/assertj-examples/blob/master/assertions-examples/src/test/java/org/assertj/examples/ListSpecificAssertionsExamples.java

Comment: Thanks. But the problem is, there you use Strings in the list. If I only have Strings, then I can use assertEquals(). But the problem is I have two objects, with the same values, which are inside two seperate lists.

Comment: Then you go and implement equals() correctly - so on your `User`  class implement equals to reflect the identity of your objects.

Answer (score 0):

The first part of your question has already been answered by Mathias. Using [PowerMock](https://github.com/jayway/powermock) would be an alternative.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(ClassUnderTest.class)
public class YourTest {

    @Test
    public void yourTest() {
        PowerMockito.suppress(MemberMatcher.method(ClassUnderTest.class, "method2"));
        ClassUnderTest m = mock(ClassUnderTest.class);
        //method2 will not be called
        m.method1();
    }
}
```

Regarding the list assertion, you can use of the powerful `samePropertyValuesAs` matcher in [Hamcrest](https://github.com/hamcrest/JavaHamcrest).

```
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.containsInAnyOrder;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.samePropertyValuesAs;

@Test
public void yourTest() throws Exception {

    ....

    assertThat(list1, containsInAnyOrder(userCollectionToMatcher(list2)));
}

public Collection<Matcher<? super User>> userCollectionToMatcher(Collection<User> users) {
    return users.stream().map(u -> samePropertyValuesAs(u)).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```